# Nullpointerexception when trying to instantiate Datepicker (com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, datepicker, vaadin, vaadin-flow

It is a bit odd, but I get straight up `Nullpointerexception` when I try to instantiate DatePicker component :

```
DatePicker date = new DatePicker("Select date", LocalDate.now());
```

Just like that, I enter the line (I already tried different parameters in the constructor and also default constructor with nothing in it), and my application does not launch due to Nullpointer...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lectureForm' defined in file [D:\IDEAProjects\university\target\classes\com\university\ui\views\forms\LectureForm.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.university.ui.views.forms.LectureForm]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.university.Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.university.ui.views.forms.LectureForm]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:309)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:85)
    at com.university.ui.views.forms.LectureForm.configureFormComponents(LectureForm.java:126)
    at com.university.ui.views.forms.LectureForm.<init>(LectureForm.java:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Line 85 (and it is always that line) in DatePicker is

```
this.setLabel(label);
```

in

```
 public DatePicker(String label, LocalDate initialDate, ValueChangeListener<ComponentValueChangeEvent<DatePicker, LocalDate>> listener) {
        this(initialDate);
        this.setLabel(label);
        this.addValueChangeListener(listener);
    }
```

And so I don't have any ideas why this is happening, why it is always the same constructor (regardless of parameters), why the problem is with the label and, most importantly, how to fix it (-:

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is your Vaadin version ?

Comment: @BenjaminD I use vaadin 16

Comment: Did you try the constructor with only the label ?

Comment: @BenjaminD yep, didn't work either (

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem - `UI.getCurrent()` returns null, and because this method is used in `DataPicker` object - `Nullpointerexception` is thorwn. But I still don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem was unexpectably Spring Boot, that I used to run application.
In IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) lines where in incorrect order, but marked with links. So `Nullpointerexception` was really thrown not at the label setting, but when method `UI.getCurrent()` was called, and `DataPicker` tried to set locale. Due to Spring (`@SpringComponent`), Vaadin UI was not yet built when method call arrived, and so the return was `null`. Solution : add `@UIScope` annotation to the class.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be reported issue about the root problem https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker-flow/issues/262